# How to parse Hypertable data using php

Tags: hypertable

I have inserted data's in Hypertable. But i don't know, how to get particular value from result. My PHP thrift code is :

```
    $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] = "/opt/hypertable/0.9.5.6/lib/php";

    require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'].'/ThriftClient.php';

    $client = new Hypertable_ThriftClient("localhost", 38080);

    $namespace = $client->namespace_open("appuniv");

    $query = "select * from category_details limit 1";

    $tab = $client->hql_query($namespace, $query);

    var_dump($tab);
```

I'm getting the below result :

> object(Hypertable_ThriftGen_HqlResult)#24 (4) { ["results"]=> NULL
>   ["cells"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(Hypertable_ThriftGen_Cell)#25 (2)
>   { ["key"]=> object(Hypertable_ThriftGen_Key)#26 (6) { ["row"]=>
>   string(32) "077262cc53a1fb1b5f651d31b6bf81ba" ["column_family"]=>
>   string(8) "category" ["column_qualifier"]=> string(4) "name"
>   ["timestamp"]=> float(1.3419935154984E+18) ["revision"]=>
>   float(1.3419935154984E+18) ["flag"]=> int(255) } ["value"]=> string(7)
>   "Medical" } [1]=> object(Hypertable_ThriftGen_Cell)#27 (2) { ["key"]=>
>   object(Hypertable_ThriftGen_Key)#28 (6) { ["row"]=> string(32)
>   "077262cc53a1fb1b5f651d31b6bf81ba" ["column_family"]=> string(8)
>   "category" ["column_qualifier"]=> string(4) "type" ["timestamp"]=>
>   float(1.3419935154984E+18) ["revision"]=> float(1.3419935154984E+18)
>   ["flag"]=> int(255) } ["value"]=> string(7) "android" } }
>   ["scanner"]=> NULL ["mutator"]=> NULL } 0.9678

May i know how to get the **["value"]=> string(7) "Medical"** value from above result.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Sort result by column family/qualifier
 * @param thrift result
 */
private function sort($data)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach ($data as $cell)
    {
        $row = $cell->key->row;
        if (!isset($result[$row])) {
            $result[$row] = new stdClass;
            $result[$row]->row = $cell->key->row;
            foreach ($this->columns as $col) {
                $pos = strpos($col, ':') ;
                $qualifier = ($pos) ? substr($col, $pos + 1) : NULL;
                $col = !$pos ? $col : substr($col, 0, $pos);
                if (!$qualifier)
                    $result[$row]->{$col} = NULL;
                else if ($qualifier[0] != '/')
                    $result[$row]->{$col}[$qualifier] = NULL;
            }
        }
        $result[$row]->{$cell->key->column_family}[$cell->key->column_qualifier] = $cell->value;
    }
    return $result;
}
```